# Как программно создать матрицу из текстбоксов?

Tags: c#, winforms

Суть в том, что имеется 2 комбобокса с числовыми значениями. Необходимо программно создать матрицу исходя из этих значений и просто поместить на форму.

Например, как на [этом](http://ru.onlinemschool.com/math/assistance/matrix/determinant/) сайте.

Хотелось бы получить ответ в виде кода, ибо в теории я понимаю, как это сделать, но на практике совсем не получается.

Comment: Используй DataGridView. Создаешь его программно, количество столбцов и строк создаешь в зависимости от условий. Это один из вариантов.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Такой вариант
[image: пример работы]

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    //имя для создаваемой панели
    private const string _TABLE_PANEL_NAME = "_tableLayoutPanel";

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //подписка на событие выбора
        _comboBox.SelectedValueChanged += _comboBox_SelectedValueChanged;
    }

    //обработчик события выбора в комбобоксе
    private void _comboBox_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //значение выбора
        var item = _comboBox.SelectedItem.ToString();

        //извлекаем требуемые количества для строк и столбцов
        int rowCount = Int32.Parse(item.Substring(0, 1));
        int columnCount = Int32.Parse(item.Substring(2, 1));

        //отобразить матрицу
        ShowMatrix(rowCount, columnCount);
    }

    //отображение матрицы
    private void ShowMatrix(int rowCount, int columnCount)
    {
        //создание TableLayoutPanel
        CreateTablePanel(rowCount, columnCount);

        //находим по имени только что созданную TableLayoutPanel
        var tablePanel = this.Controls
                                .Find(_TABLE_PANEL_NAME, true)
                                .First() as TableLayoutPanel;

        //вставляем текстбоксы
        for (int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < rowCount; j++)
            {
                var txt = $"{i},{j}";
                //новый текстбокс с текстовкой, именем, шириной
                var tb = new TextBox { Text = txt, Name = txt, Width = 30 };
                //добавляем
                tablePanel.Controls.Add(tb);
            }
        }
    }

    //создание новой панели
    private void CreateTablePanel(int rowCount, int columnCount)
    {
        //если были ранее созданы с тем же именем TableLayoutPanel
        //то удаляем их
        var oldPanels = this.Controls.Find(_TABLE_PANEL_NAME, true);
        Array.ForEach(oldPanels, new Action<Control>(c => this.Controls.Remove(c)));

        //позиция для новой панели
        Point pos = new Point { X = 10, Y = 75 };

        TableLayoutPanel tablePanel = new TableLayoutPanel
        {
            Location = pos,
            Name = _TABLE_PANEL_NAME,
            RowCount = rowCount,
            ColumnCount = columnCount
        };

        //назначаем размеры для строк и столбцов
        for (int i = 0; i < tablePanel.RowStyles.Count; i++)
        {
            tablePanel.RowStyles[i].SizeType = SizeType.Absolute;
            tablePanel.RowStyles[i].Height = 30;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < tablePanel.ColumnStyles.Count; i++)
        {
            tablePanel.ColumnStyles[i].SizeType = SizeType.Absolute;
            tablePanel.ColumnStyles[i].Width = 40;
        }

        //добавляем панель
        this.Controls.Add(tablePanel);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Первый вариант: задаём положение текстбоксов вручную.

```
int columnCount = 3; // значение из первого комбобокса
int rowCount = 4; // значение из второго комбобокса

for (int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < rowCount; j++)
    {
        var textBox = new TextBox { Parent = this, Left = j * 70, Top = i * 30, Width = 50 };
    }
}
```

Второй вариант: используем компонент `TableLayoutPanel`, который автоматически размещаем контролы на себе.

```
tableLayoutPanel.SuspendLayout();

tableLayoutPanel.ColumnCount = 3;

for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
{
    var textBox = new TextBox { Parent = tableLayoutPanel, Width = 50, Margin = new Padding(5, 5, 0, 0) };
}

tableLayoutPanel.ResumeLayout();
```

Естественно, эта панель нужного размера предварительно должна быть добавлена на форму в желаемое место.

Методы `SuspendLayout`, `ResumeLayout` используются для устранения мерцания.

Свойство `Margin` задаёт отступы. Можно оставить по умолчанию.